# stream only audio with controls to chromecast from html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, chromecast, google-cast

stream only audio with controls to chromecast from html5 javascript via browser.
i need to stream audio only to googlechromecast using my pc. i am using chrome browser. all i need to do is to stream audio only with my controls and even a screen image of the song i am playing. Currently i am not able to achive this.

```
var applicationID = 'some id';
var namespace = 'some namespace';
var session = null;

/**
 * Call initialization for Cast
 */
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}

/**
 * initialization
 */
function initializeCastApi() {
  var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
  var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
    sessionListener,
    receiverListener);

  chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
};

/**
 * initialization success callback
 */
function onInitSuccess() {
  appendMessage("onInitSuccess");
}

/**
 * initialization error callback
 */
function onError(message) {
  appendMessage("onError: "+JSON.stringify(message));
}

/**
 * generic success callback
 */
function onSuccess(message) {
  appendMessage("onSuccess: "+message);
}

/**
 * callback on success for stopping app
 */
function onStopAppSuccess() {
  appendMessage('onStopAppSuccess');
}

/**
 * session listener during initialization
 */
function sessionListener(e) {
  appendMessage('New session ID:' + e.sessionId);
  session = e;
  session.addUpdateListener(sessionUpdateListener);
  session.addMessageListener(namespace, receiverMessage);
}

/**
 * listener for session updates
 */
function sessionUpdateListener(isAlive) {
  var message = isAlive ? 'Session Updated' : 'Session Removed';
  message += ': ' + session.sessionId;
  appendMessage(message);
  if (!isAlive) {
    session = null;
  }
};

/**
 * utility function to log messages from the receiver
 * @param {string} namespace The namespace of the message
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function receiverMessage(namespace, message) {
  appendMessage("receiverMessage: "+namespace+", "+message);
};

/**
 * receiver listener during initialization
 */
function receiverListener(e) {
  if( e === 'available' ) {
    appendMessage("receiver found");
  }
  else {
    appendMessage("receiver list empty");
  }
}

/**
 * stop app/session
 */
function stopApp() {
  session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onError);
}

/**
 * send a message to the receiver using the custom namespace
 * receiver CastMessageBus message handler will be invoked
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function sendMessage(message) {
  if (session!=null) {
    session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
  }
  else {
    chrome.cast.requestSession(function(e) {
        session = e;
        session.sendMessage(namespace, message, onSuccess.bind(this, "Message sent: " + message), onError);
      }, onError);
  }
}

/**
 * append message to debug message window
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function appendMessage(message) {
  console.log(message);
  var dw = document.getElementById("debugmessage");
  dw.innerHTML += '\n' + JSON.stringify(message);
};

/**
 * utility function to handle text typed in by user in the input field
 */
function update() {
  sendMessage(document.getElementById("input").value);
}

/**
 * handler for the transcribed text from the speech input
 * @param {string} words A transcibed speech string
 */
function transcribe(words) {
  sendMessage(words);
}
```

please help. kindly let me know if there ways to achieve this.

Adding another code which i was able to modify to suite my needs. But the problem is that it only connects. the tabs shows conencted and playing but i am not hear the audio from chromecast (TV). Please help me out regarding audio streaming.

```
    'use strict';
    var DEVICE_STATE = {
      'IDLE' : 0,
      'ACTIVE' : 1,
      'WARNING' : 2,
      'ERROR' : 3,
    };

    /**
     * Constants of states for CastPlayer
     **/
    var PLAYER_STATE = {
      'IDLE' : 'IDLE',
      'LOADING' : 'LOADING',
      'LOADED' : 'LOADED',
      'PLAYING' : 'PLAYING',
      'PAUSED' : 'PAUSED',
      'STOPPED' : 'STOPPED',
      'SEEKING' : 'SEEKING',
      'ERROR' : 'ERROR'
    };

  var streamCaster = function(ele,url)
  {
    this.playUrl = url;
    this.castPlayer =null;
    this.receiverAvailable = null;
    this.init(ele);
    this.initCastPlayer();
    console.log("Playing URL "+this.playUrl);
  }


  streamCaster.prototype.init = function(ele)
  {
    console.log("Init Player");
    this.castPlayer = document.getElementById(ele);
    this.castPlayer.addEventListener('loadeddata', this.onMediaLoadedLocally.bind(this));
  }

  streamCaster.prototype.onMediaLoadedLocally = function()
  {
    console.log("Playing Audio");
    this.castPlayer.play();

  };

  streamCaster.prototype.initCastPlayer = function() {
    console.log("Init Chrome-Cast");
    if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
      console.log("No Support For Chrome Cast..Re Trying");
      setTimeout(this.initCastPlayer.bind(this), 1000);
      return;
    }
      var applicationID = 'Yr ID';
      // auto join policy can be one of the following three
      var autoJoinPolicy = chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED;
      //var autoJoinPolicy = chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.PAGE_SCOPED;
      //var autoJoinPolicy = chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.TAB_AND_ORIGIN_SCOPED;
      // request session
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
        this.sessionListener.bind(this),
        this.receiverListener.bind(this),
        autoJoinPolicy);
        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, this.onInitSuccess.bind(this), this.onError.bind(this));
  }

  streamCaster.prototype.onError = function() {
    console.log("error");
  };

  streamCaster.prototype.onInitSuccess = function() {
    console.log("init success");
    this.startChromeCast();
  };

  streamCaster.prototype.sessionListener = function(e) {
    this.session = e;
    if( this.session )
    {
      if( this.session.media[0] )
      {
        this.onMediaDiscovered('activeSession', this.session.media[0]);
        this.syncCurrentMedia(this.session.media[0].media.contentId);
        this.selectMediaUpdateUI(this.currentMediaIndex);
      }
      else
      {
        this.loadMedia(this.currentMediaIndex);
      }
      this.session.addUpdateListener(this.sessionUpdateListener.bind(this));
    }
  }

  streamCaster.prototype.loadMedia = function(mediaIndex) {
    if (!this.session)
    {
      console.log("no session");
      return;
    }
    //console.log("loading..." + this.mediaContents[mediaIndex]['title']);
    var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(this.playUrl);

    mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
    mediaInfo.metadata.metadataType = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.GENERIC;
    mediaInfo.contentType = 'audio/mp3';

    mediaInfo.metadata.title = "Castlevania Symphony Of The Night";
  //  mediaInfo.metadata.images = [{'url': MEDIA_SOURCE_ROOT + this.mediaContents[mediaIndex]['thumb']}];

    var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
    request.autoplay = this.autoplay;
      request.currentTime = this.castPlayer.currentTime;
    //   this.castPlayer.pause();
    //   this.castPlayer = PLAYER_STATE.STOPPED;
    //
    //
    // this.castPlayerState = PLAYER_STATE.LOADING;
    this.session.loadMedia(request,
      this.onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'),
      this.onLoadMediaError.bind(this));

  };

  streamCaster.prototype.onMediaDiscovered = function(how, mediaSession) {
    this.currentMediaDuration =-1;
    this.currentMediaSession = mediaSession;
    this.currentMediaSession.addUpdateListener(function()
    {
      console.log("binding");
    });
  };
  streamCaster.prototype.onLoadMediaError = function(e) {
    console.log("media error");
  };



  streamCaster.prototype.sessionUpdateListener = function(isAlive) {
    if (!isAlive)
    {
      this.session = null;
      this.deviceState = DEVICE_STATE.IDLE;
      this.castPlayerState = PLAYER_STATE.IDLE;
      this.currentMediaSession = null;

      var online = navigator.onLine;
      if( online == true )
      {
        // continue to play media locally
        this.playMediaLocally();
      }
    }
  };

  streamCaster.prototype.playMediaLocally = function() {

      this.castPlayer.load();
      this.castPlayer.play();
  };


  streamCaster.prototype.receiverListener = function(e) {
    if( e === 'available' ) {
      this.receiverAvailable = true;
      console.log("receiver found");
    }
    else {
      console.log("receiver list empty");
    }
  }

  streamCaster.prototype.startChromeCast = function() {
    console.log("launching app...");
    chrome.cast.requestSession(
      this.sessionListener.bind(this),
      this.onLaunchError.bind(this));


    if( this.timer ) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  };

  streamCaster.prototype.onLaunchError = function() {
    console.log("launch error");
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple javascript wrapper around the chromecast SDK:
https://github.com/fenny/castjs

```
var device = new Castjs()
device.on('available', function() {
    cc.cast('https://example.com/music.mp3', {
        poster:      'https://example.com/album.jpg',
        title:       'Artist - Song',
        description: 'Album'
    })
})
```

This wrapper has many more options, you can check out the documentation on the github link above

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be using the Cast SDK Media Channel to send media to the receiver. You only have support for text messages. Take a look at the reference Chrome sender app on how to play media on a Cast device: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome
The reference app is based on video but audio is very similar.

Comment: hi i am having a hard time making teh audio works. i am taching teh code i was able to modify for audio but still does not work. the brwsder is able to conenct to the chjrome cast but cannot hear audio

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser log? Have you used the Chrome Dev Tools to see if there are any issues on the receiver?

Comment: I have able to fix this issue. I was using a nodejs to host my local mp3. it was like http://localhost/static/audio/mysong.mp3  . since chromecast was not able to access it i was getting launchErrors. After moving my mp3 over the web like some web hosting it worked flawlessly. thanks for your help. but there is still one more thing , the controls does not seems to work. the above code i pasted is a bare code stripped to the minimum. anybody looking to implement audio/video can use this code.

Comment: Do you see the media status messages on the receiver when you use the controls?